# Removing dead links from Xubuntu 16.04 whisker menu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

Here is a [screenshot of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K0u4.png) with the dead link to Java 8 Mission Control. This seems to be a link to something I that wouldn't never had installed, I've only used Java 9.

It does not show up when I search the GUI in the menu editor/menulibre. The link also does not appear when I look in the file `~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu`.

There is nothing similarly named in `/usr/share/applications/` or `/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/` (which only contains `defaults.list`).

I have also restarted the panel and rebooted.

Additionally, the menu editor does not show "Oracle Java 8 Mission Control" under Development, but the menu itself does.

Comment: See my answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461929/304889 using Application Finder.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i have the same menu .. looks close .. have you tried right clicking on your `start` button and going to `edit applications` and see if it is in there to remove.. You will have to click on the little arrow to the left of Development for the items in the menu to show .. and it might be there for you to remove

Comment: Yes, that is the menu editor. I suppose I should have mentioned in the original post that in addition to having tried that, the menu editor does not show "Oracle Java 8 Mission Control" under Development, but the menu itself does.